# How to repeat top rows of a table in each page in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have a table in LaTeX which spans multiple pages.
I want the top two rows repeated in each page.
How can I do that?

Comment: LaTeX question which have the programming nature are on topic on Stack Overflow, but for most LaTeX question you're probably better posting on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ (simply because the user base is specialized). If aiobe's answer is what you wanted, this would have been better on tex.SE. If the question is how to *implement* a longtable-like macro in LaTeX, then it's a tossup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=longtab):

> ***Tables longer than a single page***
>
> *[...]*
>
> *Both longtable and supertabular allow definition of head- and footlines for the table; longtable allows distinction of the first and last head and foot.*
>
> *[...]*

Answer (score 0):

you've got to use the longtable package. Here is an example of the head (source: http://users.sdsc.edu/~ssmallen/latex/longtable.html)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline

%here your table content goes

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

\endlastfoot